# Angular app with more than one module and general functionality

Tags: angularjs, module

Angular modules are a kind of namespacing feature that we know from the .net world. Keep things contained in modules.

The problem is that I would like to do this:

1. I would like certain pages that don't have any specific client-side functionality but use custom directives to just define `ng-app` or `ng-app="xyz"` to just work; I don't want to introduce an additional Javascript code(file) just to make it work.
2. I would like to have pages with different modules i.e. `App.Main` and `App.Specific`; Both of these pages should use the same directives from #1 and use them.
3. I would like to contain general stuff inside `App.General` module, and then have additional modules like mentioned `App.Main` and `App.Specific`.

### Question

Which module should directives be defined in and how should dependencies (if at all as they don't call each other's code in any way) between these modules be for directives **and** pages to work as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly, my suggestion would be to define several angular app modules in the same javascript file and activate the appropriate one for each page by the `ng-app="App.General"` directive vs `ng-app="App.Specific"`. So you could have have a single concatenated javascript file that contains:

- angular.js
- any third party dependencies you are using
- your custom directives, services, controllers, etc

  - I would suggest using "very granular modules" as [recommended at the NYC AngularJS Meetup Feb 2014 at 24m in this video](http://youtu.be/wcdZlX3MCUg?t=24m) and putting each individual directive and service into it's own module.
  - But it would also be fine to group all your shared directives into a single module called "App.Directives", for example.
- your general code defined by `angular.module('App.General', ['MyDirective']);` (plus additional dependencies)
- your specific code defined by `angular.module('App.Specific', ['MyDirective', 'MyService']);` (plus additional dependencies)

Also note that you don't have to declare your app dependencies as a literal array of strings. You could do `var directives = ['Dir1', 'Dir2'];` Then `angular.module('App.Specific', directives.concat('MyService', 'MyController'));` to express that the specific app uses the same directives as the general app.

Each page could include the same `<script src="/bundle.js"></script>` HTML (thus it would be loaded from the web only once then cached).

General pages would include `ng-app="App.General"` in their HTML. Specific pages would have `ng-app="App.Specific"`.

> certain pages that don't have any specific client-side functionality but use custom directives

So the directives technically constitute "client side functionality" since they will be rendered to their final HTML in the browser. So you will need to load angular.js, the modules containing your directives and at least one line of your own code to define an app and declare it's dependencies on the modules that provide the custom directives you are using.

Comment: Why would I want module dependencies when they don't have any in code? And how can I use specific directives on a `App.Main` page when those directives are defined on other module...

Comment: Directives are code. They are dependencies. Your distinction here of markup (the HTML directives) and code (the javascript that declares the dependencies) is out of alignment with how angularjs works. If you want a directive to work, you need to load it's javascript into your angular app using the dependency injection system.